# Icon color stays black when I try to change it through a style

Tags: css, font-awesome

```
Rails 6
fontsawesome
```

Kind of new to stylesheets.

In my view, I have the following:

```
#BookEditIcon
  td = link_to edit_Book_path(Book)
    .fas.fa-edit.fa-lg
```

And in the stylesheet, I have:

```
#BookEditIcon {
  .fas {
    color: blue;
  }
}
```

But the icon is showing up in black, not blue. What am I doing wrong?

## Solution:

In the view:

```
td = link_to edit_Book_path(Book)
  .fas.fa-edit.fa-lg
```

And in the stylesheet

```
.fa-edit {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: When you inspect it, where are it's styles coming from currently?

Comment: You gave me the hint for the solution. I removed the ID, which removed the nesting